# Index correlation with Buffer Gets

Tags: oracle, indexing, buffer, relation

I have a questions that keep playing on my mind about the index relations with buffer gets on Oracle.

> Is that true if I put on an Index and the buffer gets decreased then the Index is considered as worked well?
>
> And is it also true that Index could also increase buffer gets and that considered as Index is not suitable for that query?

I really need an explanation for this questions.  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is added to provide better access paths to data in tables, and/or to police a unique constraint.

Buffer gets is just a measure of how many blocks Oracle had to read in order to service a query. It might read each buffer from the buffer cache, or if not found, from disk.

Since most of the time taken by queries, generally, is in reading blocks (whether from the buffer cache or from disk), I'd expect that improving a query by giving it a better access path (e.g. by adding an index) should *reduce* the number of buffers required, rather than increase them.

Comment: well but currently I have a case where I put the index on and the buffer is increased.  It's a small query to execute though (about 0.33 sec or so and after put the index it became 0.75 or so with increased buffer gets).  Is that possible?

Comment: Of course - but there are *so many* factors involved, you have barely scratched the surface in terms of determining why the buffer gets have increased.

Comment: First thing I'd do is examine the query execution plans for the query with and without the index. If you need further help with this, post the query plans (by editing your original question).

Comment: By the way, does it mean if buffer gets decreased then the execution time also reduced? Because in my place I can't really make sure if the execution time decreased because of the network traffic. I just want to make sure I'm doing it right :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd forget about buffer gets. Your users don't care how whether your buffer gets increased or decreased, they care about how long it takes for the computer to finish their request. Get the wall clock time first, then decide whether it is actually taking too long; only then will it be time to determine why. Focussing on just one metric (buffer gets) is quite possibly a waste of your time.

Comment: Yes practically that's correct. But right now I just want to do some research and I want to make sure if buffer gets has an effect with execution time. From what I gather, if the buffer gets decreased then the execution time should also decrease and vice versa. Right? Thanks for the quick response by the way.

Comment: No, you're looking for a correlation but without knowing why, any correlation may, for all you know, be a coincidence.

Comment: Yes I'm a little bit fuzzy right now because of this. Haha. By the way, let's say in a small query is it true that using an index can cause a higher disk read than without using an index?

Comment: I don't know why you would think so. The idea of using an index is usually to *reduce* the number of blocks that need to be read.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Is there any way that you could explain me a deeper more how the index works?  So that I can get a clearer view about it :)

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT811